# what is the workaround for QString.contains() method for pyqt4+python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qstring

I have been converting a Qt/C++ widget code into PyQt4+Python3. I have a QFileSystemModel defined and the items it returns have "data" with the filename as type "str". (This is of type QString in Qt/C++ or Python2x).

I have to search for a filter based on QRegEx. In Qt/C++ and Python2x this is achieved by QString.contains(QRegEx).

I found that QString has been removed in Python3. Since now in Python3 everything is now of type "str", how can i implement the old method QString.contains(QRegEx)?

Thanks,
Kodanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For string mainipulation, Python is generally superior to anything Qt has to offer (particularly when it comes to regular expressions).

But if you must use `QRegExp`:

```
    # test whether string contains pattern
    if QRegExp(pattern).indexIn(string) != -1:
        print('found')
```

Python:

```
    if re.search(pattern, string):
        print('found')
```

Comment: Yes, I am constrained to use QRegExp, since it is the ourput of a query function from a QSortPorxyModel. I tried to convert it using Python's re.compile, but I wasn't successful. But your first method works like a charm. Thanks a lot!